# register fastify swagger with helmet

Tags: node.js, fastify, fastify-swagger

i have this package version

```
"@fastify/swagger": "^8.13.0",
"@fastify/helmet": "^11.1.1",
```

trying to register swagger into fastify app

```
await app.register(import('@fastify/swagger'), app.configs.swagger);
app.register(helmet, instance => {
  return {
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "form-action": ["'self'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:", "validator.swagger.io"],
        "script-src": ["'self'"].concat(instance.swaggerCSP.script),
        "style-src": ["'self'", "https:"].concat(
          instance.swaggerCSP.style
        ),
      }
    }
  }
})
```

getting this error

```
        "script-src": ["'self'"].concat(instance.swaggerCSP.script),
                                                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'script')
```

i tried to comment it

```
          instance.swaggerCSP.style
                              ^
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
```

how can i fix it ?